# Why does LOAD DATA INFILE import 0 into MySQL database field instead of data in CSV file?

Tags: php, mysql

Hopefully this isnt a duplicate question as I have been hunting for a solution for about a year now... anyway here goes;

I have a database which is hosted on an Ubuntu Apache Server and currently shows about 2m lines of data. My suppliers upload their stockfiles regularly and every hour a cron job on my server drops the table containing the data and reimports it from their supplied files - so stock levels and prices are never more than an hour old.

Suppliers typically send their data in CSV or TXT files. I then run a MYSQL command, using LOAD DATA INFILE, from within the PHP file on my Apache server which serves the database to my users over a website.

This process works seamlessly on the whole. As you can imagine, the database comprises of data from many suppliers... and I write a unique command for each supplier to import their data from whatever format they sent. However I have issues with one supplier who uploads a CSV file, which looks fine.

If the import runs automatically using the PHP script everything gets imported (e.g Description, Price, etc) except the quantities in stock column. It only ever shows 0 in stock, regardless of what is actually entered in their quantity column. But... if I run the command from PHPMyAdmin, it works fine and the quantities are imported correctly - so I am confident the source file is not corrupt.

At the moment, I rename the CSV file to TXT in order to remove any formatting - but this has the same issue. I have also tried changing the Quantity filed from INT (4) to FLOAT (4,0), TXT, VARCHAR and it always fails.

One clue is that when the data format is set to VARCHAR the quantity data in the databse is empty, even though the source file has quantites entered... all other data types I have tried show "0".

The MySQL Command which works from PHPMyAdmin is -

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/www/html/datafiles/FTP/company/company.txt' INTO TABLE `supplier-data` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (`Man_Pt_Nr`, `Sup_Pt_Nr`, `Manufacturer`, `Description`, `Qty`, `Cost`, `Condition`) SET `Disti` = 'Company Name', `shipping` = '£10.00';
```

The MySQL Command which works, but imports the quantity values as 0, from PHP is -

```
mysql_query ("LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/www/html/datafiles/FTP/company/company.txt' INTO TABLE `supplier-data` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (`Man_Pt_Nr`, `Sup_Pt_Nr`, `Manufacturer`, `Description`, `Qty`, `Cost`, `Condition`) SET `Disti` = 'Company Name', `shipping` = '£10.00';" );
```

I have checked the number format in the quantity field in the CSV file and it shows as general with no formatting... so I am at a complete loss where to start with this. As mentioned, similar files from about 30 other suppliers are all fine and I cant see anything obvious with the source data - so am hoping someone can help as this has not worked for about a year now!

Sample of the import data is here;

```
Manufacturer part number,SKU,Manufacturer name,Product name,Quantity in stock,Price list 1,Product condition code
500208-562-2304528AS,"2304528AS","Hewlett Packard Enterprise","1GB DDR3 PC3-10600 1333Mhz DIMM 240pin Ecc (AS)","19","2.00","AS"
E5470-NL-SB198-R4,"2337083R4","Dell","LAT E5470 i5-6300U/8GB/128GB-SSD/14""HD/W10P CMAR WLAN/BT/Single Point/Cover protection sticker (R4)","2","183.00","R4"
LAT7480-NL-SB106-R4,"2337512R4","Dell","FlexIT Dell Latitude 7480 (Refurbished)  7th gen Intel® Core? i5  2.6 GHz  35.6 cm (14"")  1920 x 1080 pixels  8 GB  256 GB","68","378.00","R4"
EURO-C13-STD-5/6FT-N2,"2215545N2","Universal","EURO 230V C13 Power Cable Black 5-6ft/1 50-1 80M (N2)","14686","2.00","N2"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: May be an access problem.

Comment: Which field(s) are coming up as `0`?

Comment: Hi @user3783243... Its the fifth column - so on the first line of data, after the header row, its the "19" on the second row its "2", third row its "68" and so on.